# Install fonts programmatically under macOS (OS X)

Tags: macos, fonts

What is macOS API to install fonts globally (make them available to all applications) WITHOUT copying font files to /Library/Fonts, /System/Library/Fonts, or ~/Library/Fonts? Apparently, such API exists (just couldn't find it) because some applications, such as Adobe Creative Cloud, are able to install fonts globally while keeping the corresponding font files in custom folders (FontBook doesn't see these fonts). Under Windows, such functionality is available via GDI AddFontResourceW(LPCWSTR fontFilePath) function.